# Random function from specific sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, random

I have to create a lottery program with c#.

Tables who I use is 3.

First table :`Clients`

```
Client_num   Client_Name    Client_ID
```

Second table: `Prize`

```
 Prize_Name  Prize_ID
```

3rd Table:  `Report`

```
Prize_ID   Client_ID  ID_Number   --(who can be not unique).
```

My task is to create a form who visualize client num (between 1 to 435333, every months client num is differt, because i generated them from specific criteria).

For that I use select query in my code - who return the MAX ID from table `Clents`.

Except client num i have to visualize name of prize and this two rows have to visualize in report.
My question is - How to create Random number between 1 to 435533 as these number to be a client num from "client" table in textbox - Client number.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random Lottery = new Random();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=sqlsrvr;Initial Catalog=lottery;Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(id) AS ID FROM clients", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: `int randomNumber = Lottery.Next(1, 435533);`?

Comment: What do tables or this have to do with random numbers? Why don't you just use the [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class? Please rewrite the question, explaining the *actual* problem and posting *relevant* code

Comment: Are you asking how to return a random record from the database or how to generate a random number in c#?

Comment: A appologize to incorect question.This random numbers are correct clients from table "clients" - which I generated every month and 50 of them have to win i specific prize. Important is program Lottery to rotate client num from tables "clients" and after I push enter to download first profitable client...after that second and so to 50th.

Comment: Still not very clear. what are you asking exactly?

Comment: I think, that have to return a random records from the database because there are client num.

Answer (score 0):

Just randomly select 50 ids from your clients table

```
SELECT TOP 50 id FROM clients ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this 50 random numbers have to be withdrawn from all other numbers(435333) in lottery program. When I draw first number, press enter , draw second number and that until 50-th.

Comment: "SELECT TOP 1 id FROM clients ORDER BY NEWID()" this randomly select one id from your records(which is 435333 records in your clients table), but you might get a same id each time you draw. Why not just draw 50 at once and show one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your requirements, I have tried to summarise them below so if  this is not correct then the solution will also be wrong!

Summary:

1. You have a list of clients, each with a unique "client id"
2. Each month, the clients are entered into a lottery to win prizes
3. 50 random clients are chosen as winners.
4. The next month, the clients who have previously won are excluded
   from the lottery.
5. The remaining clients are entered to win prizes.

Points 4 & 5 are important to the problem and solution.

Based on this I would suggest the following.  This is just Pseduo code, as some parts you can do in C# or in SQL so you have the choice.

1. Extract the clients who have not previously won.

   Select ROW_NUMBER(), Client_num, Client_Name, Client_ID from clients where clients.client_id not in (select client_id from report);

ROW_NUMBER() (this might vary depending on your database) will give each record you extract a record/row number.  This is now your new temporary sequential unique id that you will use during the next part.

1. Load them into a collection such as `List<Clients>`
2. Count the number of records that you have.  This is your max.
3. Randomly pick 50 records up to your max, based on the rownumber.
4. For each of these, get the client_id and update the tables in your database to record the winners.

Now you have 50 unique winners who have never won before.

This does mean that over time the list of possible winners will get less and less, until eventually you will have less that 50 possible winners.  So you will also have to cope with this eventuality.